# React rendering black screen without errors

Tags: reactjs

React is rendering the screen with no errors, except for its blank. it needs to display hello world, as my test for it to be working. I'm using `Routes` and `Route`. Any suggestions?

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  useNavigate,
} from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";

import Search from "./pages/Search";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Reccomendations from "./pages/Reccomendations";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <div>Hello world</div>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" exact element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/reccomendations" element={<Reccomendations />} />
          <Route path="/search" element={<Search />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What about CSS? if you see black, there'll be some CSS directive that paints the background black, maybe.

Comment: Does hello world really go in the Router tag, strikes me as odd.

Answer (score 0):

i think i get your problem by default creat-react-app have dark background so its possible your text is not visible with the background color you can remove `className` prop from main `div` or add `style={{color:'white'}}` in `<div>Hello world</div>` if it still doesn't work then copy paste this in your in your `App.js` file

```
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Reccomendations from "./pages/Reccomendations";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
export default function App() {
  return (
     <>
     <BrowserRouter>
     <div>Hello world</div>
     <Routes>
     <Route exact path="/"  element={<Home />} />  
     <Route exact  path="/reccomendations" element={<Reccomendations />} />
     <Route exact path="/search" element={<Search />} />
     </Routes>
     </BrowserRouter>
     </>
 );}
```

if it still doesn't work let me know.